# Does not putting conv=fsync mean that if you shut down your computer the copy might not be complete?

Tags: dd

So from what I know conv=fsync means that the cache is fully written before dd quits. But does that mean otherwise the writing is not complete when dd quits? Like if I shut down the computer (after dd is seemingly done) the file might be left incomplete?

What about using dd to write all zeroes to a hard drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dd conv=fsync` causes dd to flush the OS cache for the file it is writing before it exits.

Normally,without this option, dd will exit as soon as the OS has accepted all the data to write.  If you shut down the OS, it will flush things to disk and unmount the filesystem before shutting down.

So, if you shut down normally, it wouldn't be a lot different than with the fsync option.  But if you ran dd without it, waited for it to finish, and then yanked the plug, all bets are off.  Of course, even with the fsync option, things might not go well if you did this, but at least dd's output would be on disk.

Similarly, if this is a removable drive, it would not make a difference if you used fsync and then ejected the disk or didn't use it and ejected the disk, except the eject would not take as long with `dd conv=fsync` since it would have fewer (no?) buffers to flush.  But if you yank the removable disk out without ejecting, it is uncertain if all the buffers would have had a chance to be written.

Possibly the biggest difference here is that the fsync option forces the OS to flush the buffers immediately while you wait for dd (or eject) to finish, where without it, they will be flushed opportunistically in the background, and the kernel may delay flushing it in favor of other I/O that gets flushed first.

The point here is that the kernel will delay some writes in favor of other more important I/O (for instance, reads, or other writes to the same device).   By using fsync (or eject), you are telling the kernel that this particular I/O is most important, finish it now.

The source of the data is not relevant here, only where the data is being written and when you wait for it.